# How do I keep scrollbar justified to the right when the body has padding?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm using a modal with a header and a body component. The body has left and right padding in order to center the text. However, this is also pushing in the scrollbar. Is there a way to keep the scrollbar justified to the right while using the padding to center the body text?

```
 <div className="CoverageInfoModalInnerBox">
            <span className="fa fa-close closeBtn" onClick={onCloseModal} />
            <div className="CoverageInfoModalInnerContent">
              <h3 className="headerText">Basic Coverage Includes</h3>
              <h4 className="subHeaderText">State Minimum Bodily Injury</h4>

              <p className="subText">
                 Some body text
              </p>

</div>

.CoverageInfoModalInnerBox {
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    background-color: $white-color;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid rgba(43, 89, 126, 0.5);
  }

.CoverageInfoModalInnerContent {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

Here, the padding from the .CoverageInfoModalInnerBox is pushing the scrollbar for the body element. I'd like to be able to right justify the body scrollbar and still be able to use the padding. Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: `padding` is not ideal for centering text. There are much better options, not the least of which is `text-align:center`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting hard values for the padding, I would look into using flex to center the text. It seems like the class **CoverageInfoModalInnerContent** is the parent. I would try adding the following code.

```
.CoverageInfoModalInnerContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I would remove the padding from the body and let flex automatically center it for you. Also is there a reason you are using the className property in HTML?

Comment: Oh this is actually a react app. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: gotcha, regardless the flexbox option should work. Have you tried it out to see if it worked for you? quick guide on flexbox here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/